# Редактирование DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Итак, есть исходный DF:

```
Год x1  x2  x3
1   5   9   8
2   6   9   7
3   7   8   8
4   9   8   9
5   9   9   8
6   8   8   7
7   9   8   9
8   8   9   9
9   8   8   9
10  9   9   8
1   5   9   8
2   5   6   5
3   6   5   4
4   6   6   4
5   6   6   5
6   4   6   6
```

Необходимо отредактировать его таким образом, чтобы `x1` соответствовали предыдущие значения `x2`,`x3`. То есть берем `x1` за второй год и ставим ему в соответствии значения за 1 год. Когда год перестает повышаться, значит пошел новый цикл, то есть заново берем второй год "второй партии". На выходе необходимо получить нечто такое:

```
Год x1  x2  x3
2   6   9   8
3   7   9   7
4   9   8   8
5   9   8   9
6   8   9   8
7   9   8   7
8   8   8   9
9   8   9   9
10  9   8   9
2   5   9   8
3   6   6   5
4   6   5   4
5   6   6   4
6   4   6   5
```

Comment: Вы вопрос забыли

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [55]: df.assign(**df[['x2','x3']].shift()).loc[df['Год'].diff() > 0].astype('int')
Out[55]:
    Год  x1  x2  x3
1     2   6   9   8
2     3   7   9   7
3     4   9   8   8
4     5   9   8   9
5     6   8   9   8
6     7   9   8   7
7     8   8   8   9
8     9   8   9   9
9    10   9   8   9
11    2   5   9   8
12    3   6   6   5
13    4   6   5   4
14    5   6   6   4
15    6   4   6   5
```

---

> А для чего в начале были две ** ?

чтобы сдвинуть значения двух столбцов:

```
In [57]: df.assign(**df[['x2','x3']].shift())
Out[57]:
    Год  x1   x2   x3
0     1   5  NaN  NaN
1     2   6  9.0  8.0
2     3   7  9.0  7.0
3     4   9  8.0  8.0
4     5   9  8.0  9.0
5     6   8  9.0  8.0
6     7   9  8.0  7.0
7     8   8  8.0  9.0
8     9   8  9.0  9.0
9    10   9  8.0  9.0
10    1   5  9.0  8.0
11    2   5  9.0  8.0
12    3   6  6.0  5.0
13    4   6  5.0  4.0
14    5   6  6.0  4.0
15    6   4  6.0  5.0
```

Comment: Великолепно, как и всегда. А для чего в начале были две ** ?

Answer (score 2):

То же самое, что написал [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944387/233990), но постепенно и без `**` - можно считать как анализ или объяснение, что делает одна мощная сложная команда в этом ответе:

1. Получим серии от столбцов:

   ```
   In[51]: s2 = df['x2']
   In[52]: s3 = df['x3']
   ```
2. Сдвинем значения этих серий:

   ```
   In[53]: s2 = s2.shift()
   In[54]: s3 = s3.shift()
   ```
3. Заменим этими сериями первоначальные столбцы в `df`:

   ```
   In[55]: df.assign(x2=s2, x3=s3)       # то же самое как df.assign(**{'x2': s2, 'x3': s3})
   Out[55]: 
       Год  x1   x2   x3
   0     1   5  NaN  NaN
   1     2   6  9.0  8.0
   2     3   7  9.0  7.0
   3     4   9  8.0  8.0
   4     5   9  8.0  9.0
   5     6   8  9.0  8.0
   6     7   9  8.0  7.0
   7     8   8  8.0  9.0
   8     9   8  9.0  9.0
   9    10   9  8.0  9.0
   10    1   5  9.0  8.0
   11    2   5  9.0  8.0
   12    3   6  6.0  5.0
   13    4   6  5.0  4.0
   14    5   6  6.0  4.0
   15    6   4  6.0  5.0
   ```
4. Из результата выберем только те строки, в которых год *более года в предыдущей строке*, т.е. те, для которых `df['Год'].diff()` будет положительным:

   ```
   In[56]: df.assign(x2=s2, x3=s3).loc[df['Год'].diff() > 0]
   Out[56]: 
       Год  x1   x2   x3
   1     2   6  9.0  8.0
   2     3   7  9.0  7.0
   3     4   9  8.0  8.0
   4     5   9  8.0  9.0
   5     6   8  9.0  8.0
   6     7   9  8.0  7.0
   7     8   8  8.0  9.0
   8     9   8  9.0  9.0
   9    10   9  8.0  9.0
   11    2   5  9.0  8.0
   12    3   6  6.0  5.0
   13    4   6  5.0  4.0
   14    5   6  6.0  4.0
   15    6   4  6.0  5.0
   ```
5. Наконец применим метод `astype('int')` чтобы все столбцы были целочисленными:

   ```
   In[57]: df.assign(x2=s2, x3=s3).loc[df['Год'].diff() > 0].astype('int')
   Out[57]: 
       Год  x1  x2  x3
   1     2   6   9   8
   2     3   7   9   7
   3     4   9   8   8
   4     5   9   8   9
   5     6   8   9   8
   6     7   9   8   7
   7     8   8   8   9
   8     9   8   9   9
   9    10   9   8   9
   11    2   5   9   8
   12    3   6   6   5
   13    4   6   5   4
   14    5   6   6   4
   15    6   4   6   5
   ```

---

*Примечание к `**` в комментарии пункта 3 (или в ответе [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944387/233990)):*

В Питоне возможно вместо *списка ключевых параметров* при вызове функции / метода, например

```
func(rows=7, columns=2)
```

использовать *словарь из них* (который возможно заранее создать):

```
params = {'rows': 7, 'columns': 2}
```

Этот словарь применяется как единый параметр, но *с двумя звездочками (`**`) перед его именем:*

```
func(**params)           # теперь то же самое как func(rows=7, columns=2)
```

Пара звездочек - договоренная метка для интерпретатора Питона, что это *не обычный* параметр, а нужно его *разбить на список ключевых параметров*.

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: @MaxU - спасибо, но я только объяснял ваш отличный.